# text to speech in gtkmm

Tags: gtkmm

Problem:(text to speech/gtk/ubuntu)

I have to read out a text in the Gtk::TextBuffer in gtk+/gtkmm.
Please let e know how can i make text to speech. which library should be used ?

OS:ubuntu 10.10
Dev:gtkmm 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)